# Insert Array into MySQL Table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am new to php and I am trying to figure out how to add the array below to a MYSQL table called "skus".

Each subarray is a sku.

each value in the subarray is an options id.  (ie. blue, green, yellow, etc.)

So, I want my table to look like this.

skuid optionid

the sku id is the primary key for the table and will autoincrement when I add the optionid values.

```
Array
 (
     [0] => Array
         (
             [2] => 27
             [3] => 17
         )

     [1] => Array
         (
             [2] => 28
             [3] => 17
         )

     [2] => Array
         (
             [2] => 27
             [3] => 18
         )

     [3] => Array
         (
             [2] => 28
             [3] => 18
         )

 )
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: You need to loop through array and use query to store values ...

Comment: where do you get your SKU ids? you cannot just create it - it should be connected to some particular SKU.

Comment: One more clarification.   I'm passing a product ID ($cid) via $_GET.  So my table actually has three columns:  skuid (auto incremental primary key integer), optionsid (the values in the array), cid (the product id I'm passing with $_GET). So every sku is iditefied by the primary key.  All the skus are assigned to a product group with the $cid.

Answer (score -2):

So your array is:

```
$skus=array(
    [SKU] => Array(
         'option' => 27,
         'option2' => 17
     )
);
```

Once you've created your mySQL table you can use the following to sort the array and input into a table:

```
$connect = mysql_connect(HOST,USER,PASS) or die(mysql_error());

$delim = ":";

$length = count($skus);

foreach ($skus as $sku => $opt_array) {

    $i = 0;
    $opts = '';

    foreach ($opt_array as $option_id) {
        if ($i == count($opt_array) {
            $opts .= $option_id;
        } else {
            $opts .= $option_id . ",";
        }
        $i++;
    }

    $query = "INSERT INTO `skus` (sku,opt_id,opt_id2) VALUES ('" . $sku . "','" . $opts . "')";

    mysql_query ($query, $connect) or die (mysql_error());
}
```

As you say you only have two columns in your table your Option ID's will have to live in the same field within your table. This is why I have declared $delim as the delimeter between option ID's.

Your actual query for the first loop through the array would be:

```
INSERT INTO `skus` (sku,opt_id,opt_id2) VALUES ('SKU','27', '17')
```

and so on.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Storing (comma)separated values in a database is generally a bad idea. Try to write a query that selects all SKU's which have option 27, for example.

Comment: I am totally aware of this... I was using it as an example. If this was me, I would have seperate table columns. Maybe I should have pointed this out rather than go with it. Thank you for saying I'm childish.

Comment: @DBDev: Childish indeed is a discriminatory term like Col. Shrapnel used it.